# Docker can't run the file

Tags: python, docker

When I prescribe docker-compose up, the following error comes out, which I don't quite understand how to fix!

**ERROR: for a1e9335fc0e8_bot  Cannot start service tgbot: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "python3 main.py": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown**

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /src
COPY req.txt /src
RUN pip install -r req.txt
COPY . /src
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  db:
    container_name: database
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:10-2
    environment:
      PG_PASSWORD: $PGPASSWORD
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - botnet
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql

  tgbot:
      container_name: bot
      build:
        context: .
      command:
        - python3 main.py
      restart: always
      networks:
        - botnet
      env_file:
        - ".env"
      depends_on:
        - db


networks:
  botnet:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: enter in the command line of your container and check that the main.py file really is where you think it should be.

Comment: Was it trying to exec a file named "python3 main.py" which has a SPACE character in its name? Try just running e.g. `date` or `ps`. Do you need the `["python3", "main.py"]` square bracket syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `command:` is in the array format, so compose thinks that the executable file is called `python3 main.py`. That doesn't exist.

Change it to this and it'll work

```
tgbot:
  container_name: bot
  build:
    context: .
  command: python3 main.py
  restart: always
  networks:
    - botnet
  env_file:
    - ".env"
  depends_on:
    - db
```

More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command).

Comment: Thank you! I've spend 1.5 hours trying to figure this out.